# Image height in flexbox not working in IE

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I have a flex "row" that contains 5 flex "cells" that contains an image which is supposed to be aligned in the middle.

It works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but it doesn't in IE. It doesn't get the good ratio. In other terms, `height:auto` doesn't work in IE when the image is in a flexbox.

I already tried several things like `flex:none;` for the image or wrap the image in another `div`. Nothing works.

I want it with the good ratio and fully centered:

Here is a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z8op323f/5/

```css
.grid-row {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
}
.grid-cell {
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  transition: box-shadow 2s;
  display: flex;
}
img {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  height: auto !important;
  min-height: 1px;
}
.long {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-row">
  <div class="grid-cell">
    <img class="long" src="http://placehold.it/350x500">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell">
    <img class="long" src="http://placehold.it/350x500">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell">
    <img class="long" src="http://placehold.it/350x500">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell">
    <img class="long" src="http://placehold.it/350x500">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell">
    <img class="long" src="http://placehold.it/350x500">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`height: auto` simply means the height of the content. It's a default value; you don't need to specify it.

If you remove `height: auto` from your code, it doesn't change anything (in any browser).

From the spec: [10.5 Content height: the `height` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#the-height-property)

---

The problem appears to be that `margin: auto` is respected in Chrome and FF. But it is being (mostly) ignored in IE 11/Edge.

This is probably a bug. IE11 in particular is known to have many *flexbugs*:

- https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs
- http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox (see "Known issues" tab)

---

A simple cross-browser solution would be to use a `margin: auto` equivalent:

Instead of this code on the flex item:

```
img {
    margin: auto;
}
```

Use this on the flex container:

```
.grid-cell {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

For more details see box #56 here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/z8op323f/7/)

```css
.grid-row {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
}
.grid-cell {
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  transition: box-shadow 2s;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;    /* NEW */
  align-items: center;        /* NEW */
}
img {
  width: 60%;
  /* margin: auto; */
  /* height: auto !important; */
  min-height: 1px;
}
.long {
  width: 80%;
  /* height: auto !important; */
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-row">
  <div class="grid-cell">
    <img class="long" src="http://placehold.it/350x500">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell">
    <img class="long" src="http://placehold.it/350x500">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell">
    <img class="long" src="http://placehold.it/350x500">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell">
    <img class="long" src="http://placehold.it/350x500">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell">
    <img class="long" src="http://placehold.it/350x500">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try adding `display: -ms-flexbox;` for IE 10

Comment: where you wrote the `display: flex;`
check this out https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/ it may help

Comment: read the question.. it's a browser compatibility problem, display flex is recognized by ie that's not the problem. Try to solve the jsfiddle before answering please. But thanks !